# How to display the stack trace in Wicket's InternalErrorPage

Tags: java, wicket

I have a custom `InternalErrorPage`, which I put into `ApplicationSettings` as follows:

```
getApplicationSettings().setInternalErrorPage(InternalErrorPage.class);
getExceptionSettings().setUnexpectedExceptionDisplay(
  IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);
getRequestCycleSettings().setUnexpectedExceptionDisplay(
  IExceptionSettings.SHOW_INTERNAL_ERROR_PAGE);
```

I want to display stack traces on this page (if I'm in development mode, of course). How can I do this?

Comment: It is bad security practice to show the stacktrace (to the customers) in PRODUCTION mode . That's why Wicket doesn't pass the exception to this page.

Comment: yes I know, that's why I wrote about development mode only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Wicket 1.4 you can use

```
getRequestCycle().onRuntimeException(new MyErrorPage(), theException);
```

Have look at the [Wicket wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Error+Pages+and+Feedback+Messages) and [the mailing list](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/error-page-td1876595.html) for further explanations.

In Wicket 1.5 onRuntimeException was [removed](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-RequestCycle). Instead you can

> "add your own org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.IRequestCycleListener (AbstractRequestCycleListener) with org.apache.wicket.Application.getRequestCycleListeners().add() and implement its #onException(RequestCycle, Exception)" (quoted from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/migration-to-wicket-15.html#MigrationtoWicket1.5-Exceptionhandling))

Comment: so you advice to put the exception in some sort of session variable? to be able then get it from the session and display it in the InternalErrorPage.java class? I just wondered - maybe it's already done by wicket itslef and I just need this exception on my own page

Comment: No, you just pass the exception to your own error-page. If you followed the links you will see that that's the way it's done in Wicket.